Getting CSRF Valid Failed 403 on my MERN Stack Project, Specifically on iOS Devices
I have a MERN Stack project (initially deployed as two different projects on Vercel, but now Vercel is deployed on Frontend and backend is deployed on Heroku).
The whole application works perfectly fine, except in iOS devices, like iPhone or Mac, where if I do a post request like sign up or sign in I get a
csrf validation failed ERRBADCSRF token 403 error. It works just fine on Windows or Android.
Here is the relevant code:
Index cors/csrf setup:
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });

const app = express();

connectDB();

const db = admin.firestore();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());

console.log('Environment:', process.env.NODE_ENV);


app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token, CSRF-TOKEN',
}));
console.log('CORS settings applied');





// Session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI
  }),
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'None' : 'Lax'
  },
}));


const csrfProtection = csurf({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, // Set to true in production
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'None' : 'Lax',
  },
});
app.use(csrfProtection);

// Middleware to set CSRF token in a cookie for all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  console.log('Generated CSRF Token:', csrfToken); // Log generated CSRF token
  res.cookie('CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken, {
    httpOnly: false, // Allow the client to access the cookie
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: 'None',
  });
  next();
});

app.get('/api/csrf-token', (req, res) => {
  const csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  console.log('Returning CSRF Token:', csrfToken); // Log token being sent to frontend
  res.json({ csrfToken });
});


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.code === 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') {
    console.error('CSRF validation failed:', err);
    res.status(403).json({ error: 'Session has expired or form tampered with' });
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
});




const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again later',
});

app.use('/api/', limiter);

app.use(helmet()); // Applies various security headers

// Initialize Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.json());

auth.js on frontend:
// src/utils/api.js
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../Constants';
import { fetchCsrfToken } from './csrf';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    try {
      const csrfToken = await fetchCsrfToken();
      console.log('Setting CSRF Token in request header:', csrfToken);
      config.headers['CSRF-Token'] = csrfToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching CSRF token:', error);
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.error('Request setup error:', error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error('Response error:', error.response.status, error.response.data);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default api;

csrf.js on frontend:
// utils/csrf.js
// utils/csrf.js
import { BASE_URL } from "../Constants";

export const fetchCsrfToken = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/csrf-token`, { // Correct usage of template literals
      credentials: 'include',
    });
    

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch CSRF token');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Fetched CSRF Token on frontend:', data.csrfToken); // Log CSRF token
    return data.csrfToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching CSRF token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

A simple handleSubmit request on a component:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // Trim all input fields to remove leading/trailing spaces
        setFirstName(firstName.trim());
        setLastName(lastName.trim());
        setEmail(email.trim());
        setPhone(phone.trim());
    
        if (validateForm()) {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('firstName', firstName.trim());
                formData.append('lastName', lastName.trim());
                formData.append('email', email.trim());
                formData.append('phone', phone.trim());
                formData.append('password', password);
                formData.append('cv', cv);
                formData.append('timezone', timezone);
    
                const response = await api.post('/instructors/register', formData);
                console.log('Registration successful:', response);
                navigate('/mentor/authentication');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Registration error:', error);
                setGeneralError('An error occurred. Please try again.');
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }
    };
    

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of, including messing around with sameSite config, cors config, including header, using credentials, use X-CSRF token as header from frontend. I have also tried adding the backend domain on Cors Origin.
I have also tried checking my domains for Front-end URL. Weirdly enough, it worked perfectly fine when i tried deploying it on Vercel as a single project (both frontend and backend deployed as single project). Even though it worked on iPhone as well, I couldn't really use that as Vercel has a few limitations on certain backend features. I have to set backend differently on a different domain.
I am desperately in need of help please!

It seems that I was using two different domains. For backend it needs to be the same domain. Rather, you need to add two different sub domains only.
Else iOS devices would consider it third party cookies and block it.
So, just make sure you have the same domain setup with two different sub domains for frontend and backend.
